# Sort each row in 2D array without changing the original

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to sort the array m1 and print it

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Foo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] m1 = { { 14, 11, 13, 12 },

                { 18, 15, 13, 13 },

                { 19, 16, 15, 17 } };

    int[][] temp = m1.clone();

    sortRows(m1);

    displayArray(m1);

    m1 = temp;

}

public static int[][] sortRows(int[][] m) {

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {

        Arrays.sort( m[i] );

    }

    return m;

}

public static void displayArray(int[][] m) { 

    //method to print array

  }
}
```

How do remove the array duplication and reverting to the original in the main method? I want to move it to the SortArrays method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each array in your multi-dimensional array (in Java) is also an `Object`, so you need to perform a deep copy of each one. If I understand your question, you could do something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] m1 = { { 14, 11, 13, 12 }, { 18, 15, 13, 13 },
            { 19, 16, 15, 17 } };
    int[][] temp = new int[m1.length][]; // <-- a new array for the copies.
    for (int i = 0; i < m1.length; i++) {
        temp[i] = m1[i].clone();         // <-- copy each row.
        Arrays.sort(temp[i]);            // <-- sort each row.
    }
    System.out.println("Original: " + Arrays.deepToString(m1));
    System.out.println("Sorted copy: " + Arrays.deepToString(temp));
}
```

Output is

```
Original: [[14, 11, 13, 12], [18, 15, 13, 13], [19, 16, 15, 17]]
Sorted copy: [[11, 12, 13, 14], [13, 13, 15, 18], [15, 16, 17, 19]]
```